# Multiple jQuery libraries gives conflict

Tags: javascript, jquery, conflict, slick.js

I have a problem using multiple jQuery and js plug-ins and they seem to get in conflict. This is the error I get from the console:

*"Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function"*

Directing me to main.js > ($.scrollTo(scrollPosition + "px", 800, { axis: 'y' });)

The problem occurred when I was trying to add a slider (slick) to my webpage. Can someone help me with this problem individually?

The code just before closing my  tag looks like this:

```
    <script src="js/vendor/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/vendor/jquery.scrollTo-1.4.3.1-min.js"></script>

    <script src="js/plugins.js"></script>
    <script src="js/main.js"></script>
    <script src="js/detail.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/slick/slick.min.js"></script>
    <script> 
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('.single-item').slick();
              //setting-name: setting-value
        });
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: Easiest (and best) solution - don't use multiple jQuery libraries - only use one.

Comment: Why are you using multiple jQuery libraries AND jQuery migrate?

Comment: I may kill myself if I see 2 jQuery libraries loaded on any page!

Comment: as for why, the second version is wiping out the first version and any plugins that were bound to it

Answer (score 0):

You do not need a different inclusion of jQuery for each plugin, 1 is enough.

```
    <script src="js/vendor/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/vendor/jquery.scrollTo-1.4.3.1-min.js"></script>

    <script src="js/plugins.js"></script>
    <script src="js/main.js"></script>
    <script src="js/detail.js"></script>
    <script src="js/slick/slick.min.js"></script>
    <script> 
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('.single-item').slick();
              //setting-name: setting-value
        });
    </script>
</body>
```

The only exception is when you're trying to use a plugin written for say, jQuery 1.2.6 that isn't at all compatible with the latest version. However, i would suggest instead finding a new plugin in that case.

Comment: After removing unnecessary jQuery versions, I think that the problem is that this plugin is not compatible with the jQuery version I use. Thanks for your help, and for taking me serious ;)!